# Access JSON elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have some JSON data here http://pastebin.com/5VeJ5dda

How do I access `ipaDownloadUrl` on each case and put them in two variables in PHP?
 I already did

```
<?php
$api = url_get_contents("http://example.com/api");
$decoded_api = json_decode($api);

?>
```

Now can you help me what to do next to get the specified elements?

Comment: `print_r` the decoded JSON to see its structure.

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve

Comment: `print_r` (or otherwise understanding the JSON structure) is critical to *doing* what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like that:

```
<?php
$api = url_get_contents("http://example.com/api");
$decoded_api = json_decode($api);

echo $decoded_api['InfiniteApp']['ipaDownloadUrl'];

?>
```

Comment: You didn't even read my question, neither the JSON data

Comment: @Jakeashacks I read your question, and understood it just as Imphusius did. Perhaps you're being unclear?

Comment: You didn't see there are two ipaDownloadUrl? I want each of them in two separate variables

Comment: @Jakeashacks Then use `print_r` to understand the structure. `$decoded_api['InfiniteApp']` appears to be an array. Step through them with a for/foreach loop.

Comment: I know in javascript I can do this: `data.InfiniteApp[0].ipaDownloadUrl` and `data.InfiniteApp[1].ipaDownloadUrl`. This is what I want to do in PHP

Comment: @Jakeashacks That's entirely doable in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: OK, I got someone to answer me. It was so simple. `$decoded_api->data->InfiniteApp[0]->ipaDownloadUrl`. Anyone here couldn't answer. Hah